# Do questions on search engine optimization belong here? If not, where do they belong?

Tags: support, allowed-topics

E.g. I want to ask a question like: http://www.quora.com/SEO/If-you-re-use-your-Internet-name-on-numerous-sites-is-there-a-way-to-make-your-name-on-one-site-appear-before-your-name-on-another-site

But I'm not sure if they belong here.

Comment: Thanks for asking here first!

Answer (score 5):

Questions on Search Engines are offtopic as mentioned in the [FAQ](https://superuser.com/faq)

and it is not about …

- videogames or consoles
- **websites or web services** like Facebook, Twitter, and WordPress
- electronic devices, media players, cell phones or smart phones, except insofar as they  -  interface with your computer
- a shopping or buying recommendation

Questions on search engine optimization is  on-topic for [Web Masters Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com).